# Why i cannot invoke java method via HTML/JS in IntelliJ ToolWindow plugin?

Tags: javascript, java, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I'm creating a plugin for IntelliJ IDEA that needs to load local static web content(HTML, CSS, JS) into a ToolWindow and invoke a java method from that HTML/JS content. I used JavaFX WebView to load the HTML content into the ToolWindow. But when I tried to invoke the Java methods from HTML or JS, it didn't work, and sometimes it's giving fatal error and crashes the application.

Please let me know is there any other way to integrate static web content into ToolWindow. Please find the sample codes below.

```
public class MyToolWindow implements ToolWindowFactory {

private JFXPanel jfxPanel;

@Override
public void createToolWindowContent(@NotNull Project project, @NotNull ToolWindow toolWindow) {
    toolWindow = ToolWindowManager.getInstance(project)
            .getToolWindow(Messages.getMessagePropertyText(Messages.PLUGIN_TITLE));

    JPanel myPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    jfxPanel = new JFXPanel();
    createScene();
    myPanel.add(jfxPanel);

    Content findingPanel = toolWindow.getContentManager().getFactory().createContent(myPanel,"",false);
    toolWindow.getContentManager().addContent(findingPanel);
}
public void invokedFromJS() {
    System.out.println("Invoked from JS");
}

private void createScene() {
    Platform.setImplicitExit(false);
    Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            BorderPane borderPane = new BorderPane();
            WebView webComponent = new WebView();
            WebEngine webEngine = webComponent.getEngine();

            webEngine.documentProperty().addListener((obs, oldDoc, newDoc) -> {
                JSObject window = (JSObject) webEngine.executeScript("window");
                window.setMember("app", new TestClass());
            });

            webEngine.load(MyToolWindow.class.getResource("/mypage.html").toString());

            borderPane.setCenter(webComponent);
            Scene scene = new Scene(borderPane,450,600);
            jfxPanel.setScene(scene);

        }
    });
}}
```

mypage.html

```
 <html>
 <head>
    <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Insert title here</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
       function m() {
          try {
             window.app.onClick();
          }catch(err) {
             console.log(err);
          }
       }
    </script>
 </head>
 <body>

 <button onclick="m()">Click ME</button>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Why do you set the member inside an event listener?

Comment: Actually that's one of suggestion that I got from the community. Previously I tried without the event listener. But didn't work either.